# Why is my Log4j code not working here?

Tags: java, log4j

I'm having trouble running my log4j code, and I believe it 's a configuration issue;  here is how I run it :

```
C:\Users\Adel\JavaCoding>javac -cp  C:\apache_log4j_beta5\apache-log4j-2.0-beta5
-bin\log4j-api-2.0-beta5.jar;C:\apache_log4j_beta5\apache-log4j-2.0-beta5-bin\log4j-core-2.0-beta5.jar;. HelloWorldLog4J.java
```

But I'm getting this error :

> C:\Users\Adel\JavaCoding>java HelloWorldLog4J Exception in thread
>   "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/lo
>   g4j/LogManager
>           at HelloWorldLog4J.(HelloWorldLog4J.java:11) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
>
> ```
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>     ... 1 more
> ```
>
> C:\Users\Adel\JavaCoding>

Comment: you need to specify the `log4j` jar in the classpath when you run the `java` command

Comment: @ipohfly  -  I did add it to classpath, but  for some reason that doesn't work .. so I did it manually like so. Which does compile btw

Comment: Possible to post the command that you run the `java` command with the classpath? The one posted is for `javac`

Comment: @ipohfly - Ah, my apologies - I read it wrong. Ok I see what you mean thnx

Comment: So you mean I should not call it simply like `java HelloWorldLog4J`  , but with arguments

Comment: yes, something like `java -cp <path-to-my-jar-files> HelloWorldLog4J`

Comment: @ipohfly THANK YOU !!!!! It worked It finally worked :-) !!!!

Answer (score 0):

As user ipohfly (thank you !!! ) said, I must use `java` command with the `-cp` argument like so:

```
C:\Users\Adel\JavaCoding>java -cp  C:\apache_log4j_beta5\apache-log4j-2.0-beta5-
bin\log4j-api-2.0-beta5.jar;C:\apache_log4j_beta5\apache-log4j-2.0-beta5-bin\log
4j-core-2.0-beta5.jar;. HelloWorldLog4J
```

and this yielded the output desired :

> pre_loggerDOTinfo
>
> 22:51:33.973 [main] FATAL HelloWorld - Hello, this is an FATAL 
>   message 22:51:33.997 [main] FATAL HelloWorld - Hello, this is an FATAL
>   message ALSO, #2
>
> 22:51:33.997 [main] FATAL HelloWorld - Hello, this is an FATAL 
>   message ALSO, #3
>
> 22:51:33.997 [main] FATAL HelloWorld - Hello, this is an FATAL 
>   message ALSO, #4
>
> post_loggerDOTinfo
>
> C:\Users\Adel\JavaCoding>